# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'int'

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting the above error when I am trying to run my query in Linq Pad which is as below,

```
var qry = (from i in INTERNETDATAs 
join c in COVERS on Convert.ToInt32(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
where  i.DATELOADED >= new DateTime(2013,7,1)
&& i.DATELOADED < new DateTime(2013,8,1)
&& i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == "4"
&& c.COVERTYPEID == 17063789
&& c.CHILDAPPLIES  != 1
&& c.SPOUSEAPPLIES != 1
select i
);

qry.Dump();
```

The column c.CHILDAPPLIES and c.SPOUSEAPPLIES in my COVERS table are of (bit, null) type.

My Sql query is working fine which as below but my  LINQ query gives error Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'int'

```
SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM INTERNETDATA I Join COVERS C ON  C.COV_TYPE = CONVERT(int, I.COVERTYPE) 
    WHERE ((I.DATELOADED >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 Jul 2013 00:00:00')) 
    AND (I.DATELOADED < CONVERT(DATETIME, '1 Aug 2013 00:00:00'))) 
    AND (CONVERT(int, I.COVERTYPE) = C.COV_TYPE)
    AND (C.COVERTYPEID = 17063789)
    AND (I.CAMPAIGNTYPE = 4) 
    AND C.CHILDAPPLIES != 1
    AND C.SPOUSEAPPLIES !=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `Linq` you can not use Convert.ToInt32()

Comment: @AmitAgrawal You *can* use `Convert.ToInt32()` in `Linq`.  Some `Linq` **expression converters** might not support it however (Linq-to-Entities for example).

Answer (score 9):

I suspect you just want:

```
&& !c.CHILDAPPLIES
&& !c.SPOUSEAPPLIES
```

... although you should consider whether you want this to match rows where the columns are NULL rather than true or false. If the above doesn't compile (which it may not) you can effectively provide the "default" value with the null-coalescing operator:

```
&& !(c.CHILDAPPLIES ?? true)
&& !(c.SPOUSEAPPLIES ?? true)
```

or

```
&& !(c.CHILDAPPLIES ?? false)
&& !(c.SPOUSEAPPLIES ?? false)
```

The problem is that in the LINQ mapping, they're not "0 or 1" values - they're "true or false" values (or null) - so you can't compare them with integers.

Answer (score 2):

try following i think this what you want

```
var qry = (from i in INTERNETDATAs 
join c in COVERS on Convert.ToInt32(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
where  i.DATELOADED >= new DateTime(2013,7,1)
&& i.DATELOADED < new DateTime(2013,8,1)
&& i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == "4"
&& c.COVERTYPEID == 17063789
&& c.CHILDAPPLIES  != true
&& c.SPOUSEAPPLIES != true
select i
);

qry.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest it is one of these 2:

```
&& c.CHILDAPPLIES  != 1
&& c.SPOUSEAPPLIES != 1
```

Even though they are of type `Bit` linq will compare them as boolean

Answer (score 1):

If it returns bool? couldn't You just compare it with True or False?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CHecking it using '!=' Operator,Use

```
!c.CHILDAPPLIES && !c.SPOUSEAPPLIES.
```

This Might help